# How to encode zip files as part of multipart/form-data

Tags: node.js, encoding, zip, multipartform-data, slack

**tldr I'm having encoding issues when sending zip files as part of a multipart/form-data request body. Help please :/**

I'm working on a bot that should be able to upload zip files to Slack (via their file api), but I'm running into some issues that I believe are related to encoding.

So, I'm creating my request body as follows:

```
var form_string = "\n--abcdefghijklmnop\nContent-Disposition: form-data; filename=\"" + filename + "\"; name=\"file\";\nContent-Type:application/octet-stream;\nContent-Transfer-Encoding:base64;\n\n" + data;
form_string += "\n--abcdefghijklmnop\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"token\";\n\n" + token;
form_string += "\n--abcdefghijklmnop\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"filetype\";\n\n" + filetype;
form_string += "\n--abcdefghijklmnop\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"filename\";\n\n" + filename;
form_string += "\n--abcdefghijklmnop\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"channels\";\n\n" + channel;
form_string += "\n--abcdefghijklmnop\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"title\";\n\n" + title;
form_string += "\n--abcdefghijklmnop--";

var form = Buffer.from(form_string, "utf8");

var headers = {
  "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=abcdefghijklmnop",
  "Content-Length": form.length,
  "Authorization": "Bearer ....."
};
var options = {
  "headers": headers,
  "body": form 
};
// using the sync-request node module. 
var res = request("POST", url, options);

var res = request("POST", url, options);
```

(I've tried `application/zip` and `application/x-zip-compressed` as well. I've also tried both binary and base64 content transfer encodings.)

(And in case you're wondering, I need to make synchronous http requests...)

I created a really small zip file as a test. The base64 encoding of it is below:

`UEsDBAoAAAAAAAqR+UoAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAIABwAdGlueXppcC9VVAkAA1PBd1mDwXdZdXgLAAEE9QEAAAQUAAAAUEsDBAoAAAAAAAuR+Up6em/tAwAAAAMAAAAQABwAdGlueXppcC90aW55LnR4dFVUCQADVsF3WVzBd1l1eAsAAQT1AQAABBQAAABoaQpQSwECHgMKAAAAAAAKkflKAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACAAYAAAAAAAAABAA7UEAAAAAdGlueXppcC9VVAUAA1PBd1l1eAsAAQT1AQAABBQAAABQSwECHgMKAAAAAAALkflKenpv7QMAAAADAAAAEAAYAAAAAAABAAAApIFCAAAAdGlueXppcC90aW55LnR4dFVUBQADVsF3WXV4CwABBPUBAAAEFAAAAFBLBQYAAAAAAgACAKQAAACPAAAAAAA=`

What I'm getting from Slack seems to be similar to the original... maybe...

`UEsDBAoAAAAAAArCkcO5SgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgAHAB0aW55emlwL1VUCQADU8OBd1nCg8OBd1l1eAsAAQTDtQEAAAQUAAAAUEsDBAoAAAAAAAvCkcO5Snp6b8OtAwAAAAMAAAAQABwAdGlueXppcC90aW55LnR4dFVUCQADVsOBd1lcw4F3WXV4CwABBMO1AQAABBQAAABoaQpQSwECHgMKAAAAAAAKwpHDuUoAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAIABgAAAAAAAAAEADDrUEAAAAAdGlueXppcC9VVAUAA1PDgXdZdXgLAAEEw7UBAAAEFAAAAFBLAQIeAwoAAAAAAAvCkcO5Snp6b8OtAwAAAAMAAAAQABgAAAAAAAEAAADCpMKBQgAAAHRpbnl6aXAvdGlueS50eHRVVAUAA1bDgXdZdXgLAAEEw7UBAAAEFAAAAFBLBQYAAAAAAgACAMKkAAAAwo8AAAAAAA==`

Could someone explain what encoding is going on here and how I can correctly upload a file to Slack? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about following sample scripts? There are 2 patterns for this situation.

#### Sample script 1 :

For this, I modified the method you are trying. You can upload the zip file by converting to the byte array as follows. At first, it builds `form-data`. It adds the zip file converted to byte array and `boundary` using `Buffer.concat()`. This is used as body in request.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var upfile = 'sample.zip';
fs.readFile(upfile, function(err, content){
    if(err){
        console.error(err);
    }
    var token = '### access token ###';
    var filetype = 'zip';
    var filename = 'samplefilename';
    var channel = 'sample';
    var title = 'sampletitle';
    var formString = "\n--abcdefghijklmnop\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"token\";\n\n" + token;
    formString += "\n--abcdefghijklmnop\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"filetype\";\n\n" + filetype;
    formString += "\n--abcdefghijklmnop\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"filename\";\n\n" + filename;
    formString += "\n--abcdefghijklmnop\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"channels\";\n\n" + channel;
    formString += "\n--abcdefghijklmnop\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"title\";\n\n" + title;
    formString += "\n--abcdefghijklmnop\nContent-Disposition: form-data; filename=\"" + upfile + "\"; name=\"file\";\nContent-Type:application/octet-stream;\n\n";
    var options = {
        method: 'post',
        url: 'https://slack.com/api/files.upload',
        headers: {"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=abcdefghijklmnop"},
        body: Buffer.concat([
            Buffer.from(formString, "utf8"),
            new Buffer(content, 'binary'),
            Buffer.from("\n--abcdefghijklmnop\n", "utf8"),
        ]),
    };
    request(options, function(error, response, body) {
        console.log(body);
    });
});
```

#### Sample script 2 :

This is a simpler way than sample 1. You can use `fs.createReadStream()` as a file for uploading to Slack.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
request.post({
    url: 'https://slack.com/api/files.upload',
    formData: {
        file: fs.createReadStream('sample.zip'),
        token: '### access token ###',
        filetype: 'zip',
        filename: 'samplefilename',
        channels: 'sample',
        title: 'sampletitle',
    },
}, function(error, response, body) {
    console.log(body);
});
```

#### Result :

Both sample 1 and sample 2 can be uploaded zip file to Slack as follows. For both, even if `filetype` is not defined, the uploaded file is used automatically as a zip file.

[image]

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Your first solution worked perfectly! Thanks :)

Just making sure -- you just have to decode and convert everything into an array of bytes, right?

Comment: @graceyin Welcome. Thank you, too. Yes. In order to upload binary data, both the binary data and strings have to be encoded to byte array. The base64 data might be able to be used for this. But when the data size is thought, the size using byte array is less than the size using base64. I have never tried to use base64 for this situation. I'm sorry.